# Disabling SublimeText autocomplete on open parentheses

Tags: javascript, jquery, sublimetext2

In SublimeText 2, when I type:

```
$('#whatever').val(
```

All of the sudden, it autocompletes that entire section to:

```
$('#whatever').val(value, function);
```

It puts the cursor on `value`.  The problem is, I simply want this:

```
$('#whatever').val();
```

It is a pain-in-the-butt to always have to remove the autocompleted stuff there to get what I want.  Is there a way to turn this off without turning off auto_match?

**EDIT**: Turning off autocomplete does not help. That only seems to disable the suggestions that are made when hitting Ctrl+Space or when I get a popup with suggestions after typing the name of a function. This appears to be a completely different matter whereas when I type the opening parentheses, it automatically fills in the stuff stated above without any suggestions.

Comment: Is this only happening when the file extension is javascript? Are you using any plugins or other packages?

Comment: Holy crap... it was the SublimeCodeIntel package.  It updated recently which caused this to happen.  Thanks for reminding me to check that!

Comment: I had the same issue with the `print()` function in Python - I'd open the parens and all the default values would suddenly spill out. I think they've fixed it now...

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be due to the SublimeCodeIntel plugin. There was a recent update that seemed to cause this behavior. Once I turned this plugin off, it stopped causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, although I was using Anaconda for ST3.

I managed to find the two parameters that were causing variables in the Documentation of a specific method, to be filled in between the parenthesis.

```
"complete_parameters": false,
"complete_all_parameters": false,
```

Those two parameters have to be false in your User settings for Anaconda package to prevent autocomplte to kick in and complete stuff you don't want.